# PowerShellで単語検索して一部だけを取得したい

Tags: powershell, batch-file

**list.txt**

```
ID101,4,ドリランド,1,2,3,4,5
ID102,5,ランド,1,2,3,4,5
ID121,4,ドリームランド,1,2,3,4,5
ID131,4,ドリラド,1,2,3,4,5
ID401,5,ドリラ,1,2,3,4,5
```

**コマンド(batch-file)**

```
PowerShell Select-String "ランド" "list.txt"
```

**出力結果**

```
data\list.txt:1:ID101,4,ドリランド,1,2,3,4,5
data\list.txt:2:ID102,5,ランド,1,2,3,4,5
data\list.txt:3:ID121,4,ドリームランド,1,2,3,4,5
```

この出力結果を以下のように一部分だけを出力することは可能ですか？
可能でしたら是非ご教授くださると助かります。

**理想**

```
ID101,ドリランド
ID102,ランド
ID121,ドリームランド
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

カンマでデータを区切るCSVでlist.txtが書かれているなら、次の方法で抜き出せます。

```
import-csv ./list.txt -Header ("h1","h2","h3")|%{
    if( $_.h3 -match "ランド" ){
        $id=$_.h1
        $name=$_.h3
        "${id},$name"
    }
}
```

Comment: 無事に動作してくれました。ありがとうございました。